# get Facebook Graph api page review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get review/rating from certain place whos fb page can look like this i.e :

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dell-Rheas-Chicken-Basket/183254918389428

So id of this place/page is `183254918389428`

And you can get the details of this place but not rating/review:

https://graph.facebook.com/183254918389428

I found somewhere on this forum that you could get review from page like this :

https://graph.facebook.com/183254918389428/tabs/reviews?access_token=xxx

But I always get no data :

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

So I'm not trying to get app review/rating but for certain place.

Comment: Hi, have you found solution for this i am also unable to get ratings and reviews, FQL query also returns same blank data array response.
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT rating FROM review WHERE reviewee_id = 114448512302

Comment: @prasad No I have not found it, they don't have it or don't offer it for users to consume

Comment: ok, thanks for reply, currently i am showing place facebook page that will work as its showing that place ratings and reviews, looks like its only way until we get working API officially.

Answer (score 9):

You'd need a page access token to fetch reviews and ratings. Here is a very good short tutorial on getting a page access token: [Obtaining page access token](http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/obtaining-facebook-page-access-tokens-the-4-step-program/).

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URL>&scope=manage_pages&state=<STATE>
```

This will generate you a `CODE`, use that code in:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&code=<CODE>
```

This will return you a json response containing short lived user access token.

Next, use the short lived user token to get long lived user token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&fb_exchange_token=<SHORT_LIVED_TOKEN>
```

This will return another json containing the long lived user token, you can now exchange it for page access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<LONG_LIVED_TOKEN>
```

This will return you a json with page access token of the page(s) associated with that user account. Use this page access token to fetch ratings and reviews by passing it to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/StoneArmsInc/ratings?access_token=<page_access_token>
```

And you will get all the ratings posted on facebook for that page.

Hope, this helps someone. :)

Comment: Does it mean that the long live access_token is exposed in the client (web browser)?

Comment: Thanks !
Helps me a lot !

Comment: @JimitShah Did you get the reviews and rating from above solutions?

Comment: @ManeeshRao : Yes , I got it , but I executed this code in 2017 , it's 2020 , there will be so much changes done in Facebook. Some of things are deprecated officially , so there will be some of change in code , but I confirm in 2017 , I got the ratings and reviews in 2017 :)

Comment: Can you please help me what was the approach to get the reviews and ratings? Can I get the other facebook business reviews and ratings?

Answer (score 4):

The ratings edge has the reviews in it now, but you need to have a page access token to get it.

The end point is documented here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings

Note that to get the page access token you have to use a user token from someone who is an admin of the page. I don't know if that's a problem for you.

Comment: It's completely correct. A sample call could look like: `FB.api('/{page-id}/ratings', 'GET', { access_token: '{access-token-from-page}' }, function (Response) { });`

Comment: `This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v3.2.`

Answer (score 1):

The API for Page reviews hasn't been released yet. We are working on it. Please keep checking for the updates [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/).

Update: API for fetching page reviews can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

Comment: Long shot, but.. is there any ETA on that, or something I can subscribe to get a notification of when this is going to be available. Nothing really on the page linked which can help me with that.