# Get facebook page rate and reviews using Graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am creating website to search places using graph API. I got the places details from graph API. Is there any way to get the page rating and reviews of the places via graph API?

Comment: I just answered this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315839/get-facebook-graph-api-page-review/20797173#20797173. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904843/can-i-use-the-graph-api-to-add-comments-to-ratings/21929874):

you need to call **{page-id}/ratings?field=open_graph_story**, but you need the access token of your page for that (use /me/accounts in the Graph API Explorer to get the token). You find further information in the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/).

Comment: Thanks Sascha. Reminded me I needed to use the page token not the main access token.

Comment: Sascha, I am trying your answer but it is not working for me. My app have manage_pages permission. could you help with . I am getting error '''This call requires a Page access token." and code is

Comment: <?php

require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';



$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '148904733XXXXXX';
$config['secret'] = '6ac210360aad27ab1044XXXXXXX';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
print_r($facebook);

try {

 $ret = $facebook->api("/1633988186866636/ratings?field=open_graph_story", 'GET');
 print_r($ret);
} catch(Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}

Answer (score 6):

This is an old post, but I wanted to give some extra info to others that might be looking for a solution to this problem still. As stated in the [Facebook Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/), **you definitely need a page access token to get the page's individual ratings/reviews**. If you are looking for the *overall rating* and the *count of reviews*, however, you are in luck. By simply making a call to `/{page-id}?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count`, you will be able to access that data.

Here's an example response:

```json
{
    "overall_star_rating": 4.7,
    "rating_count": 31,
    "id": "{page-id}"
}
```

Comment: Hi David, can you please elaborate? E.g. how would I get those 2 fields with PHP, I tried the following code but it didn't work (I'm a bit of a newbie):  $raw = file_get_contents('https://facebook.com/Yuga-Floral-Design-by-Setsuko-382079515143204?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count');
    $obj = json_decode($raw);
    echo $obj->overall_star_rating;

Comment: Hi David, I need some help regarding the facebook API. Can we access ratings of any public page ? I know to access the ratings we need page id and page access token. Suppose I have page id (of some random public page of Facebook), can I generate the access token using /me/accounts in the Graph API Explorer ? And then can I fetch the ratings of that page ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

David R. Myers II's answer is just what I needed. Thank you!
You can get the `overall_star_rating` and the `rating_count` fields of any page.

You need to submit your app for review by Facebook and request to use the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) feature.

For developing, while your Facebook app status is `In development` you automatically have access to the public content for pages that you own. Before going live, request a review from Facebook so you can access other pages.

To list pages you own: https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages?ref=u2u

Sample code to get the ratings:

```
// Assuming the Facebook PHP SDK was installed with Composer.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // Change path as needed.

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{app-id}',
    'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
    'default_access_token' => '{access-token}',
]);

try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphPage object for the needed page.
    $response = $fb->get('/{page-id}?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// Get the response typed as a GraphPage.
$page = $response->getGraphPage();

// Get the needed field values.
$facebook_rating_count = $page->getField( 'rating_count' );
$facebook_overall_star_rating = $page->getField( 'overall_star_rating' );
```