# Can I use the graph api to add comments to ratings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is possible to grab the comments data with the [{page-id}/ratings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/) call. The resultset of that call shows all rating entries without ids. Is there a way to add comments to those ratings? The documentation says that this should be possible if the story is generated, but I don't have a plan to generate that story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, found it.

you need to call **{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story** to get a list of all public reviews, including the object id. With these objects you can add comments:
**(POST) {object-id}/comments**

Comment: Is ratings data public? Or do we need a page access token to get that? That's what it says in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings), so only page admins can read the reviews data.

Comment: You need to have the page token and you only see the ratings that are visible on the page. If you create a rating which is visible for your friends, you will not be able to access that rating with the page token.

Comment: So only the page admins can get the ratings data?

Comment: That won't be possible for a lot of places, would it? :) Thanks for clearing this out for me.

Comment: FYI, you can call `{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story{comments}` to get the comments with the ratings.