# Authenticating with Facebook Graph API & Parsing JSON Reviews from a Facebook Page

Tags: json, parsing, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble authenticating and parsing.

[get Facebook Graph api page review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315839/get-facebook-graph-api-page-review)

I have tried to submit the app for review and request manage_page access but I get an error:

"Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions" and possibly the API is deprecated

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/FinancialSanityNow/ratings";
         var getToken = function(req, res) {
         var facebookToken = req.headers['facebooktoken'];
         //TODO : check the expirationdate of facebooktoken
         if(facebookToken) {
            var path = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/FinancialSanityNow?access_token=' + facebookToken;
         request(path, function (error, response, body) {
            var facebookUserData = JSON.parse(body);
         if (!error && response && response.statusCode && response.statusCode == 200) {
          if(facebookUserData && facebookUserData.id) {
            var accessToken = jsonWebToken.sign(facebookUserData, jwtSecret, {
                //Set the expiration
                expiresIn: 86400
            });
            res.status(200).send(accessToken);
         } else {
           res.status(403);
           res.send('Access Forbidden');
                             }
         }
         else {
           console.log(facebookUserData.error);
           //console.log(response);
           res.status(500);
           res.send('Access Forbidden');
         }
         });
           res.status(403);
           res.send('Access Forbidden');
         }
         };
         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'access_token':'xxxxxaccesstokenherexxxxx',
         },

            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data){
                    $.each(data.reviews, function(i, item) {
                        // Store each review object in a variable
                        var reviewdata = item.data.reviews;
                        // Append our result into our page
                        $('#results').append('test:' + reviewdata);
                  });
            }
         });     

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I just want to know if this is even possible through pages/ratings api from facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

Comment: "I get an error" - ALWAYS post the EXACT error message, if you get an error. that´s pretty much the number one rule for any question from developer to developer.

Comment: about the access token: is it a page token? and hopefully you don´t put the token in your client code?

Comment: the error that shows up in the JSON data is "manage_page" permission required to access. And yes it is a page token.

Comment: do you try with a user that has a role in the app settings? how do you get the access token? again, is it a PAGE token? (not a user token or app token)

Comment: Yes, when I try with a user access token I get the error: "Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions" This is why I think the resource might be deprecated, however, I think it is possible with the page access token and the manage_page permission. I have posted on the facebook developer forum. If someone doesn't reply there I will contact official Facebook developers and ask.

Comment: you MUST use a page token of that page, and you can only get one with the manage_pages permission. is your app live in the app settings?

Comment: I wonder if im requesting the wrong type of access token from the backend though, one from a facebook App instead of just page view access or something, but i swear the only permission i selected was view content.

Comment: yes i turned the app on it is live, I think I need to figure out why it won't enable that permission for me :(

Comment: ok, then i´m pretty sure i know the problem. i will create an answer. just comment below the answer if you need more info then.

Comment: btw, you should use the official JS SDK instead, it´s a lot easier to do api calls and login stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Most permissions need review before you can use them. Without review, they will only work for users with a role in the App, and you need to keep the App in dev mode. If you put it live, unapproved permissions will not work at all.

Also, you have to use a Page Token of the Page in question to get reviews, you get a Page token by using the `/me/accounts?fields=access_token` endpoint, with a User Token that includes the `manage_pages` permission.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for explaining.